# How can I stop the result of file_get_contents [PHP] from being processed as HTML?

Tags: php

I am using the PHP function `file_get_contents` to read and display the contents of some `.txt` files.

If the contents of the file is HTML code, how can I display this as a string instead of the page treating it as HTML?

My current code is something like this:

```
<?php
$load_desc = file_get_contents(/url/of/my/file.txt);
echo "<div>$load_desc</div>"
?>
```

which works fine if the file contents is plain text but, for example, if the contents contains `<img>` tags, an image will be displayed.

Sorry if this is really easy. I'm just starting out with PHP.

Comment: How about not looking at the results in a browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on it:

```
<?php
$load_desc = file_get_contents(/url/of/my/file.txt);
echo "<div>" . htmlspecialchars($load_desc) . "</div>"
?>
```

This converts unsafe characters to their entity references:

- `&` to `&amp;`
- `"` to `&quot;`
- `<` to `&lt;`
- `>` to `&gt;`

This means that you can safely inject them into your HTML and the tags will appear as plain text.

Comment: For some reason I have to wait another 4 minutes to mark it as answered (?)

Answer (score 3):

You need to call [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to HTML-escape the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$load_desc = file_get_contents(/url/of/my/file.txt);
header('Content-type: plain/text');
echo "<div>$load_desc</div>"
?>
```

this will show all content as a plain text. but if you need to get rid of the tags or show them as is you can use either `strip_tags` or `htmlspecialchars` repsectivly.

Comment: Wrong answer. Payload is within a div, which is an HTML element itself. Using plain/text displays odd div tags